# How to parseInt a number that start with 0?

Tags: javascript

I have this string: `'044600171940'`.
I want to parse the string to a number with `parseInt`, but the value returns a number without the `0` in the front.

Is it possible to return the number with a leading `0` (e.g. `044600171940`)?

```js
var arr = ['044600171941','044600171940'];

var last = arr[arr.length -1];
var number = parseInt(last)
console.log(number)//44600171940
```

Comment: This is not possible as far as I know. Why do you need the 0 in the front, and why do you need it as a Number?

Comment: a leading zero also means *octal* number in javascript proper. 04460017170 (7 replacing 9) has numeral value of 616570488...

Comment: because i have to increment to 1 example: 044600171940 ---> 044600171941

Comment: Do the numbers always have 12 characters in length?

Comment: Just do your math and once you're done use [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) to prepend the `0` again *(need to turn the number back into a string)*.

Comment: @RickardElimää yes always have 12 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`padStart(int, character)` fills up the start of a string until the length is `int` characters long.

```js
var arr = ['044600171941','044600171940'];

var last = arr[arr.length -1];

const addToNumberString = (intStr, value) => {
  let originalLength = intStr.length
  let sumInt = Number(intStr) + value;
  let sumIntStr = String(sumInt);

  return sumIntStr.padStart(originalLength, '0');
};

console.log(addToNumberString(last, 1)) // '044600171941'
```

...and here is a solution based off the fact that the value is always 12 characters long.

```js
const numberLength = 12;

const addPadding = (number) => {
  return String(number).padStart(numberLength, 0);
};

var arr = ['044600171941','044600171940'];

var last = arr[arr.length -1];
var number = parseInt(last)

console.log( addPadding(17) )         // '000000000017'

console.log( addPadding(number) )     // '044600171940'

console.log( addPadding(number + 1) ) // '044600171941'
```

Comment: Might as well make `numberLength` a function parameter, kinda weird it is in the global scope. Maybe even as default parameter -> `(number, numberLength = 12) => {}`

Comment: Depends on how both the method and the variable is used. If `numberLength` is just used in one place, then I agree, but it seemed more like a global variable. I typically have a bunch of global constants in my larger projects so I can do a minor change in a lot of places in an easy way.